# No option "Erase Ubuntu and reinstall"

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, usb-installation

Good afternoon.

Characteristics:

Laptop ASUS, the main system Windows 11, Intel CPU, Nvidia GPU, dual boot Ubuntu 20.10 (broken beyond repair)

There was a problem when reinstalling Ubuntu from bootable USB.

I wanted to upgrade from Ubuntu 20.10 LTS to the latest 23.10.
The update failed (I understand why), the old version won't start.

I wrote a bootable flash drive.
Installer and Try ubuntu start, but at the moment of installation selection there is no option "Erase Ubuntu 20.10 and install 23.10".

There is only the option to split disks or completely format the entire disk.

Are there any ways to fix this?

My main goal to install the latest version of Ubuntu, and keep Windows 11 intact

Comment: Do a "something else" install and manually set up the Ubuntu partitions. Don't touch the windows ones.

Comment: When I click "something else" there nothing can be selected for some reason

Comment: There are lots of questions on this site about that sort of problem. I'm not personally familiar with it, so please search the site, but ISTR it's because you're mixing the install modes (MBR vs UEFI) or possibly some BIOS setting.

Comment: Is Windows fast startup/hibernation on, or bitlocker on? That prevents the partitioning tools from seeing the Windows install. Note that 23.10 is a short term release. If you want support for longer term use 22.04 and plan to upgrade to 24.04 in April. Do you have good backups. You can do a "dirty" install where you do not format Linux partition. It may keep most of your data, but resets every system setting back to defaults. Better to have good backup. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation

Comment: Everything I needed already has been saved :) so I am good with full reinstall

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. USB does see Windows and old Ubuntu. It is just not want to erase the old one